# Issue On Passing PHP Variable to jQuery

Tags: javascript, php

Trying to pass variable from PHP to jQuery I have a line of code as:

```
<script>
var modelID = <?php echo $modelID; ?>;
</script>
```

on my js script but I am getting this error in result:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Is the file with the javascript code in it a .php file?

Comment: Hi Brendan , yes they are!

Comment: View-source... what does it look like?

Comment: Yes. Look at what the generated source is. Could actually be an error, in which case xdebug (or a similar debugging module) is wrapping it in HTML for a pretty output. Are you sure `$modelID` is indeed accessible at that point in the script?

Answer (score 2):

may be you miss single quote :

```
<script>
var modelID = '<?php echo $modelID; ?>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this script is within a `.php` file (or one that is configured to be parsed by PHP), and your `$modelID` variable is set in the current scope, I'd recommend the following...

```
var modelID = <?= json_encode($modelID) ?>;
```

See [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

This is a message produced by javascript, so it means that either your php code is not executed (interpreted by php) and javascript does not know what to do with `<?php echo $modelID; ?>;` or `$modelID` has '<' in it. I think that the first one is the case, show the content of `$modelID`.

Answer (score 0):

try with [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/function.json-encode.php):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var modelID = <?php print json_encode( $modelID ); ?>;
</script>
```